# Test-driven Data Analysis?

Tags: r, database, statistics

Several R packages have been developed that allow you to make assertions about your data, results of analysis, etc. However, I have never seen anyone compile a list of useful checks.

Are there any resources that have checklists or other lists of common checks?

For example, if you were analyzing survey data, you might want to sanity check the data as follows:

- Impossible values: Someone who lists a profession of doctor is 6 years old
- Unlikely correlations: Education level has a negative correlation with Earnings

After doing a lot of joins, you want to verify the final data structure:

- Lost observations: A data set begins with N = 100,000... after appending variables, does N still equal 100,000?
- Unreasonable values within columns: Summaries of nulls, detection of outliers, distribution of most common values
- Unreasonable cross-column relationships: A table with sales references salesperson, but the salesperson ID doesn't exist in the salesperson table

After developing predictions, you want to check if they make sense:

- Unlikely predictions across groups: You average predicted probabilities of making a purchase by group and find that non-pet owners are more likely than pet owners to buy pet food

etc. etc.

Below are some **R** packages that would help incorporate such tests into **R**... if only we had a checklist of what those tests should be!

---

**testthat**

http://journal.r-project.org/archive/2011-1/RJournal_2011-1_Wickham.pdf
https://github.com/hadley/testthat

**RUnit**

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RUnit/vignettes/RUnit.pdf

**Svunit**

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/svUnit/vignettes/svUnit.pdf

Comment: This sounds like a very difficult task to do in general.

Comment: I'm sympathetic to the aim of this question, but SO isn't really the right place for this style of question.  Note that `caret` has some functions such as `findZeroVar` that do something of this nature.  Another thing you might want to check for is values that are obviously missings not coded that way (e.g. `-9` in a numeric vector in a survey).

Comment: The packages mentioned are mostly for syntax checking while the goals of your request are better handled by the several functions with the name "describe". I use Hmisc::describe and plot(density(x, na.rm=TRUE)) for my initial checks. The task of automatically checking for impossible combinations is really the job of a human being but the `table` command may be useful.

Comment: What you describe is closer to 
[contract-based programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract), i.e., checking 
[pre-](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precondition) and 
[post-conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postcondition) 
for each step in your computations, rather than test-driven design.
In R, I simply use `stopifnot` to check those conditions,
but the tests are very specific to the nature of your data and your computations.

Comment: @AriB.Friedman -- perhaps this question should be migrated to the statistics stack overflow? I don't intend this question to be opinion-based and would be interested in links to checklists for data/analysis validation. Would that fit within the QA style?

Comment: I think CrossValidated (the stats.SE site) would think of this as mostly a programming question, unfortunately.

Comment: @AriB.Friedman - God forbid the statisticians write good code for validating their data!